# Cookie not working when taken from python script

Tags: python, asp.net, cookies

I am trying to open a url http://krishimaratavahini.kar.nic.in/reports/DailyMar.aspx. 
But you can't open it without session. When i try to take the cookie fron session in python script using

```
s = requests.session()
cook = s.cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"]
```

,it doesn't work. But when I open http://krishimaratavahini.kar.nic.in/reports/Main_Rep.aspx and take its cookie from browsser and the pass it to the python script it works. Can someone please explain this and help me solving this problem?

The code is :

```
source_url = "http://krishimaratavahini.kar.nic.in/reports/Main_Rep.aspx"
s = requests.session()
content = s.get(source_url).content
cook = s.cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"]
url = "http://krishimaratavahini.kar.nic.in/reports/DailyMar.aspx"
headers={
"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate,sdch",
"Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.8",
"Cache-Control":"max-age=0",
"Connection":"keep-alive",
"Cookie":"ASP.NET_SessionId="+cook,
"Host":"krishimaratavahini.kar.nic.in",
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36" }
a=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print a.content
```

Comment: Just a hunch: tried `s.get(source_url)`? I believe the cookie will only end up in the session when the request is done from the session.

Comment: @akaIDIOT still it is not working.